# In Residual Sum of Squares, why is $\sum(x_i-\hat{x})^2(y_i-\tilde{y})^2/\sum(x_i-\tilde{x})^2$ the minimizer?

Tags: residue-calculus, linear-regression

In Residual Sum of Squares, why is $\sum(x_i-\hat{x})^2(y_i-\tilde{y})^2/\sum(x_i-\tilde{x})^2$ the minimizer for a in $y=ax+b$ and why is $\tilde{y}-a\tilde{x}$ the minimizer for $b$ when trying to solve for $a$ and $b$ when minimizing the residual sum of squares equation?

Residual Sum of Squares:
$\sum(y-\hat{y})^2$, where $\hat{y}$ is the prediction by a function and $y$ is the actual value.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/readings/least_sq_intrpol.pdf

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang but doesn't a derivative of 0 mean it could be the min or max yes? It's not obvious to be off the RSS function that the derivative of 0 with respect to a would be the minimum.

Comment: It seems to me that there is simply no maximum of residual squares since you can move the regression line down or up indefinitely and create larger and larger sums of residual squares...